# FTP SSL through PeopleCode/Soft

Tags: ssl, ftp, peoplesoft, peoplecode

I'm trying to use PeopleCode to get a file from a remote FTP server that uses SSL. The GetAttachment command returns error code 8, which indicates a problem connecting or authenticating with the "destination server" (which I'm assuming means "remote server"). I don't think the problem is in my code itself, although I'm not discounting that, but rather in the URL configuration and the security certificate.

First, my PeopleCode is:

```
&returnCode = GetAttachment(URL.MY_FTP_URL, &fileName, &destinationPath);
If &returnCode = %Attachment_Success Then
   [...]
Else
   MessageBox(0, "", 0, 0, "Fail: " | &returnCode)
End-If;
```

I've created the URL definition via PeopleTools > Utilities > Administration > URLs. The URL is pretty straight forward. The URLID is "ftps://[remote server]/". I know this connection requires active mode and SSL, so I've added the properties (in addition to username and password) ACTIVEMODE = Y, and SSLUSAGELEVEL = 3.

Now, here is where I think the problem is. By adding the SSLUSAGELEVEL property, I also need to add the CERTALIAS property and (presumably) set it to the name of the SSL certificate. So I got the certificate, uploaded it and created the definition. I went back to the URL definition, added the CERTALIAS property, but the prompt box for the valid values is empty.

I think my problem now is that I need to perform some other step to get the certificate I created to show up in the CERTALIAS prompt. Is my approach generally in the right direction? Or am I missing something else entirely?

Thanks,

Comment: When you say you "created the definition", did you setup the certificate under PeopleTools -> Security -> Security Objects -> Digital Certificates?

Answer (score 0):

First, confirm that it is working at the operating system level.

I have noticed that GetAttachment does not always copy over the ssl certificate with the proper file system permissions, in Oracle linux, to the app server working directory and because of the incorrect file permissions, the destination server will refuse the connection.

I had to create the key file with the correct file permissions and hardcode the path to this key file, with the correct file permissions, in the URL entry.